# how can I use CLion to run the c++ program in the commands and without cmake

Tags: c++, clion

I just want to know how to use CLion to run the c++ program in the commands and without the Cmake. Can anyone help me? (I can use MinGW

Comment: What do you mean? Cmake is a part of MinGW

Comment: I want to run it like use "G++"